# Create a new point from a reference point, degree and distance

Tags: python, geos

I'm trying to calculate the coordinate of endPoint  using the lat/lon of startPoint as a reference.  I know the distance between the start and end points and I know the azimuth to the endPoint.  I found one example using [Geod](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/python-libraries-geospatial-development) but i'd like to hopefully do this in python with Geos and with WGS84 or similar spheroid model.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do the calculation on the plane, or on an ellipsoid/spheriod (if so, which one)?

Comment: i was hoping to follow WGS84 or something similar.

Comment: There is a complexity / accuracy tradeoff here. It would help if you can edit your question to say what you really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why with Geos?

I've used [pygc](https://github.com/axiom-data-science/pygc) (based on Spheroid) for another Python solution (excerpt below)

```
from pygc import great_circle

# New point from initial point, distance, and azimuth

great_circle(distance=111000, azimuth=65, latitude=30, longitude=-74)
{'latitude': 30.41900364921926,
'longitude': -72.952930949727573,
'reverse_azimuth': 245.52686122611451}
```

You can also use QGIS ["Azimuth and Distance Plugin"](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/)

Answer (score 3):

Another method I found:

```py
import pyproj

endLon, endLat, backAzimuth = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')
            .fwd(startLon, startLat, forwardAzimuth, distance)
```

See: http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html#fwd